# Broadcast Receiver not working from the service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to register two broadcast receivers in a Service that starts as soon as the application gets installed on the device. And this service also starts if the device reboots (using on boot completed receiver).

The service starts an activity where all the UI changes and notifications are triggered. The broadcast receivers register inside the service work fine till the app is in Foreground or Background state. But If I kill the app. None of the Receivers Seem to respond.

This is the code for my Service

```
public class StartupService extends Service {


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();


        Log.i("Easy Charger Service","Service Started");
        this.registerReceiver(ChargerPluggedInReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED));
        this.registerReceiver(ChargerPluggedOutReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED));
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i("EASYCHARGER", "Service is Running");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver ChargerPluggedInReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Toast.makeText(StartupService.this, "Charger Plugged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent startup_intent = new Intent(StartupService.this,Home.class);
            startup_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startup_intent);



        }
    };

    public BroadcastReceiver ChargerPluggedOutReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("EASYCHARGER", "ChargerPluggedOut");

            if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED )){             
                Log.i("EASYCHARGER", "ChargerPluggedOut - Performing Action Now");

                //unregisterReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver);
                Toast.makeText(StartupService.this, "Charger Unplugged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    };



}
```

This is my Activity Class

```
public class Home extends Activity {

    private SharedPreferences p;
    private TextView batterylevel;
    private Battery b = null;
    private NotificationsManager nm = null;
    private Button goto_tasks_act;
    private Button settings;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Context cont;
    private TextView easy;
    private boolean isFirstRun;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        cont = getApplicationContext();
        p = this.getSharedPreferences("FirstRun", MODE_PRIVATE);
        isFirstRun = p.getBoolean("FirstRun", true);
        if(isFirstRun)
        {
            Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
            shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            Intent addIntent = new Intent();
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "EasyCharger");
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher));

            addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            this.sendBroadcast(addIntent);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = p.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("FirstRun", false);
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Registering Startup Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Home.this, StartupService.class);
              Home.this.startService(serviceIntent);
        }



        Typeface batman = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/batmfa__.ttf");
        TextView easy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_tv1);
        TextView charger = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_tv3);
//      easy.setTypeface(batman);
//      charger.setTypeface(batman);

        batterylevel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        batterylevel.setText("Charging...Only Even Notifications");


        settings=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, Settings.class));
            }
        });

        RegisterAllReceivers(Home.this);

        goto_tasks_act = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        goto_tasks_act.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //startActivity(new Intent(Home.this,Tasks.class));
                new ClearTasks().execute();
            }
        });

        NotificationsManager nm = new NotificationsManager(getApplicationContext());
        nm.AppActivatedNotification();
    }


    public void RegisterAllReceivers(Context context){
        Log.i("EASYCHARGER","Registering All Receivers");
        context.registerReceiver(ChargerPluggedInReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED));
        context.registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));        
        context.registerReceiver(ChargerPluggedOutReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED));
    }


    public BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       ...

            }
    };






    public BroadcastReceiver ChargerPluggedInReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("EASYCHARGER", "ChargerPluggedIn");
            if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED )){                
                Log.i("EASYCHARGER", "ChargerPluggedIn - Performing Action Now");



            }

        }
    };

    public BroadcastReceiver ChargerPluggedOutReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("EASYCHARGER", "ChargerPluggedOut");

            if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED )){             
                Log.i("EASYCHARGER", "ChargerPluggedOut - Performing Action Now");

                //unregisterReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver);
                finish();

            }

        }
    };



    }
```

Comment: It's obvious that if you kill the app, you are stopping the service itself. So, your receivers won't receive anything because the service is no longer present.

Comment: When The app installs it starts for the first time, I start my Service that gets the Receivers registered. Now even if the app is stopped how come the service gets destroyed and so do the receivers ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean 'kill the app'?

> Starting with 3.1 when applications are installed they are in a “stopped” state so they will not be able to run until the user explicitly launches them. Pressing Force Stop will return them to this state.
>   As a result, when applications are first installed, they are totally ignored by the system until and unless the user manually launches something: clicking on a launcher activity or adding an app widget, most likely.

So is normal that if you kill the app. None of the Receivers will respond.

Answer (score 0):

starting the service in its own process using the android:process attribute in manifest might solve this problem